# Box Shadow is not working in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a question about IE8 with css box-shadow problem.

```
.box-shadow 
{
   background-color: #fff;
   margin-bottom: 18px;
   box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px #888, 0px 0px 2px #888;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color=#888);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try**

```
box-shadow:
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=10, Color='#19000000'), 
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=10, OffY=20, Color='#19000000'), 
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=20, OffY=30, Color='#19000000');
```

There is an alternative to that Use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) which will provide you other CSS3 properties like *border-radius* etc. for **IE 8, 7 and 6**.

**Better Workaround**

Use **[SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/)** with **[Compass](http://compass-style.org/)**. This will provide you all cross browser css code with one line of box-shadow code.

To use SCSS and Compass together use this **[Scout App](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/)**

Comment: If this answer helps you, please make a vote up or mark it correct :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on this [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) site, `box-shadow` is supported from IE 9+

Comment: box-shadow is not supported IE 8?

Answer (score 0):

**TRY this**

Better u can check this link. It will help you to get the solution

[CSS3pie](http://css3pie.com/)

PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features.